# MVC2 - Trying to pull a textbox's value into Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to perform some realtime phone-number validation using javascript.  I don't need help on the validation; I just need help pulling the value from the textbox into a Javascript variable.

However, on page load, I'm getting an error that says, "The name 'txtPhone' does not exist in the current context."

Here is where I declare the textbox in MVC2:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.phone, new { id = "txtPhone", onblur = "checkPhoneNumber();" })%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone) %>
</div>
```

On the same page, I have this javascript:

```
function checkPhoneNumber() {
    var phone = $("#<%= txtPhone.ClientID %>").value;
}
```

If I comment-out the txtPhone reference in Javascript, the page will load, and I can see the ID is properly assigned to the text box as follows (from View Source):

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input id="txtPhone" name="phone" onblur="checkPhoneNumber();" type="text" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to work with ASP.Net server controls, which MVC doesn't use.
You only need `ClientID` because ASP.Net server-side controls emit unique IDs in their generated HTML.

ASP.Net MVC does not create any server-side controls; `TextBoxFor` will aways use the ID you provide it as-is.

Comment: are you saying that I should just remove the "ClientID" suffix from my Javascript?

Comment: Thanks.  You were right, I just needed $("#txtPhone").val() .

Answer (score 1):

Using straight Javascript you can get a reference to the TextBox with

`document.getElementById('myText')`

but it looks like you are using a framework (jQuery perhaps)?  If you are using jQuery I believe the syntax is

`$("#txtPhone")`

either way, once you get a reference to the text box, setting the value should work the way you are trying.